# Render emoji in :emoji: format

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, emoji

I'm trying to render some **emojis** in **UITextView**, but they're in **:emoji:** format, e.g muscle emoji is :muscle:, after reading a lot on web, can't find what format is ...
How to properly render this kind of emojis ?

Thanks

Comment: "Emoji shortcodes" You would have to replace each one of string (like ":muscle:" by the emoji (UTF character) corresponding manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These emoji shortnames (like `:muscle:`) are not officially assigned by the Unicode Consortium. There is no implementation in the iOS SDK to do this by default. Therefore you need to use some existing project or implement this yourselves.

If you use the [StringEmojize](https://cocoapods.org/pods/StringEmojize) pod, you can convert a string with emoji shortnames to a string with actual emojis as follows:

```
let stringWithShortNames = "This is a test :muscle:"
let stringWithEmojis = stringWithShortNames.emojizedString()
print(stringWithEmojis) // This is a test
```

Comment: @Steve You're welcome! I just updated my answer to refer to a pod that's actually implemented in Swift (instead of Objective-C). You might want to check out the new link :)